# Migrate PB7 to 10.5 using SQL server DB

Tags: sql-server, sybase, powerbuilder

I migrated PB7 to PB10.5 on SQL server DB. The system gives me this message:

> "DBMS MSS Microsoft SQL Server 6.x is not supported in your current
>   installation"

I changed the database connection settings from: 
Old connect used in PB7:

- DBMS = MSS Microsoft SQL Server 6.x
- Database = databaseName
- ServerName = serverName
- LogId = LogId
- AutoCommit = 1
- DBParm = ""
- UserId = userid
- DatabasePassword =
- LogPassword=password
- Lock=
- Prompt=0

To this in PB10.5:

- DBMS =SNC SQL Native Client(OLE DB)
- Database =databaseName
- ServerName =serverName
- LogId =LogId
- AutoCommit = 0
- DBParm = "
- Database='databaseName'
- TrimSpaces=1"
- UserId=userid
- DatabasePassword=
- LogPassword=password
- Lock=
- Prompt=0

The system run without previous error message,but when retrieve any old stored arabic data in datawindows it seem unreadable like

> ÚãáíÇÊ ÇÎÑì

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe this question got overlooked -- sorry about that. It is a common question when migrating from older versions of PowerBuilder to PowerBuilder version 10 and higher. Good news, very easy to fix just can be time consuming depending on how many places you need to fix.

I've already written a blog article on the subject or just duckduckgo migrating PowerBuilder Unicode issues.

[Converting ANSI and Unicode Strings for PowerBuilder Migrations to Version 10 and Higher](http://www.displacedguy.com/tech/powerbuilder-converting-ansi-and-unicode-strings/)

Here is a summary of the conversion process:

**Convert data to ANSI**

```
Blob lbl_data
lbl_data = Blob("PowerBuilder is cool!", EncodingANSI!)
ls_data = String(lbl_data, EncodingANSI!)
```

**Convert data read via file to ANSI**

```
Blob lbl_data
lbl_data = Blob("PowerBuilder is cool!", EncodingANSI!)
ls_data = String(lbl_data, EncodingANSI!)
```